# Instagram API's self/feed replacement

Tags: api, instagram

Few weeks ago Instagram changed their API and removed self/feed. What is the replacement? How now I can get feed of all my subscriptions?

Comment: It looks like there is simply none :)

Answer (score 3):

The `/users/self/feed` endpoint [has been deprecated](https://www.instagram.com/developer/deprecated/endpoints/users/#get_users_feed) with no replacement.

Comment: Aaron, so, how I can get the feed of whom I'm folowwing?

Comment: There is not an easy way to do it. Instagram doesn't want 3rd party consumer Instagram apps. You could get a list of users that you are following (`/users/self/follows`), get the media for each of those users (`/users/user-id/media/recent`) and then combine it yourself.

Comment: Apparently removing the feature gives "more control to the community". http://tmblr.co/Zda_5q1yGk8FM

Answer (score 0):

Agreed, seems like Instagram already removed this endpoints. As for 1 June 2016, i cannot use the endpoint although my apps is older than this regulation. Sadly, we should remove the features of user feed in our apps.

Comment: Nah... we just have to do some actual WORK to get the features to behave in a similar way. :)